# Add Active class to menu based on url

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I am working on website. I already have functionality of adding active class in menu. My query is i have two pages in website products2 and subproducts. If i visit this i want to add active class on products.php.

here is my js code

```js
<script>
   $(document).ready(function($){
           
     // Get current path and find target link
     var path = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
      
     // Account for home page with empty path
     if ( path == '' ) {
         path = 'home.php';
     }
          
     var target = $('ul li a[href="'+path+'"]');
     console.log(path);
       
     // Add active class to target link
     target.addClass('active ');
  });
    
</script>
```

Comment: thanks ehsan. i am new on stckoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to answer the question really please try to reiterate the question.

but on first look you may want to remove the space you have behind active

```
                  target.addClass('active');
                      });
```

so it looks like this ^

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your navbar

```
class="nav-link <?= (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'home.php') ? "active" : "" ;?> "
```